# How much finger curl is considered good piano technique?

Tags: piano, technique

I saw this video and the pianist fingers curl a lot. I was always under the impression that too much curl is bad. You cannot argue with the results, but I was just wondering what the deal is with finger curl for pianists?

Is it a case of every pianist anatomy is slightly different. So teachers have to be open to having pupils just figure out what works for them or are there some absolutes?

Comment: Can you provide a timestamp where you consider Kissin to curl his finger too much, so we can have a common reference of what we are talking about?

Comment: As far as I can tell, he only over-curls fingers that aren't touching keys.  The fingers that are down look like they're curled the way I was taught.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kissin curls quite a lot..

Glenn Gould was renowned for his flat fingers.  "He played using a flat-fingered approach, taught to him by his teacher Alberto Guerrero. Interestingly, the tendency to keep one's fingers flat was also taught in the Russian school".   Though when you look, they aren't THAT flat!

I don't think it's particularly about personal anatomy.  More the way you were taught, and personal preference.

[Gould - Goldberg](https://youtu.be/eZCSOdi19jQ)